# How to pass AngularJS expressions to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass **AngularJS Expression** value to the controller.

**HTML code :**

```
<div data-ng-controller="AlbumCtrl">
<div data-ng-repeat="z in songInfo">
      <div data-ng-repeat="b in z.album">
  {{b.tracks}}
      </div>
</div>

 <!-- Pagination   -->      
 <div class="pageing">
<a class="prev" data-ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" data-ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1">prev</a>
<a class="pageingg" href="#/song">{{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}</a>
<a class="next" data-ng-disabled="currentPage >= data.length/pageSize - 1" data-ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1">next</a>
</div>

</div>
```

Here `{{b.tracks}}` is the count of total number of tracks in the album. I have to pass this data to the controller `AlbumCtrl`.

**Controller :**

```
.controller('AlbumCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $scope.album_id = $routeParams.albumId;
    $http.post('api-call.php', { albumid: $scope.album_id, evt: 13 }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.songInfo = data;
      }); 
    
    //Pagination
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.pageSize = 10;
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.numberOfPages=function(){
        return Math.ceil($scope.data.length/$scope.pageSize);                
    };
    for (var i=0; i<AngularJS expression value; i++) {
        $scope.data.push("Item "+i);
    }
});
```

Here, in controller **AngularJS expression value** is the value we have to get here.

Comment: Since you can access `songInfo` in your controller, I don't think you need to pass expression to Controller again.

Comment: When you want to pass this values to controller?

Comment: @RameshRajendran, At starting point so that i can break records into chunks(10-10).

Comment: `{{b.tracks}}` your expression having lot of values by every repeat action, then what records you want to get?

Comment: No..it have only one value..total number of tracks in an album..I just want to pass it in controller to paginate the data.

Comment: @RohitJindal I don't understand what you want to do in for loop?

Comment: @pankajparkar, I updated my question..please check now..I want to do pagination on the records get by ng-repeat thats it.

Comment: @RohitJindal are you going to show pagination of each `songInfo` element?

Comment: @pankajparkar I want to show pagination of (0-10,10-10,20,10 and so on..) records from `songInfo` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it have only one value. then you can easily get the values from controller, you don't need to pass it.

try this way `$scope.songInfo[0].album[0].tracks`

Something like

```
  for (var i=0; i< $scope.songInfo[0].album[0].tracks; i++) {
        $scope.data.push("Item "+i);
    }
```

Comment: `{"root":{"code":0,"message":"Success","album":[{"albumid":51411,"albumtitle":"Sophia","artist":"Ben Pol","rating":3,"tracks":1,"image":"https://www.aaa.com/img/060/0030/039/08/060003003908127_0.jpg"}],"tracks":[{"rcode":"0600030037","title":"Sophia","albumid":51411,"albumtitle":"Sophia","artistid":135866,"artist":"Ben Pol","genreid":88,"genre":"Bongo Flava","filesize":2066611,"duration":251,"stream":"-","image":"https://www.aaa.com/img/060/0030/039/08/060003003908127_0.jpg","videoId":"81i3dybdi8U"}]}}` this is the array and i want to fetch `track` field from the `album` array..i.e.1

Answer (score 0):

Try this two line,

```
var obj = JSON.parse($scope.songInfo);
var track = obj.root.tracks[0];
```